# Problema al instalar Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estoy tratando de instalar visual studio 2015 professional en windows 10, durante el proceso de la instalación me mando mensajes de que no podía instalar ciertos paquetes porque el archivo esta dañado o no se encuentra, le seguí con la instalación y al final me lanzó las siguientes ventanas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desactive mi antivirus, inicie el instalador nuevamente y le di en reparar, al finalizar me lanzó otra ventana en donde solo decía que se repararon ciertas cosas (pero no puso que cosas) y que necesitaba reiniciar, la pregunta aquí es como se que si reparó esos errores??

Comment: Intenta desinstalar el programa con todos sus archivos y vuélvelo a instalar.